slow movement when trying to increase player x or y and mouse is inactive
When trying to move the player from L to R or from U to D the speed at which the player moves is slow unless I start moving the mouse around.
This does not happen when decreasing the players x or y. I tried having x or y increase to different keys but that didn't work. Here's a link to a showcase gif when player speed = 800 and one for 300 player speed.
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640*2
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 640
#define BLOCK_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH / 20)
#define BOARD_HEIGHT (SCREEN_HEIGHT / BLOCK_SIZE)
#define BOARD_WIDTH (SCREEN_WIDTH / BLOCK_SIZE)

enum GridStates {
    EMPTY,
    SOLID,
    PLAYER,
};

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
float playerSpeed = 300;
int playerRadius = 15;
SDL_Point player = {SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2};

enum GridStates board[SCREEN_HEIGHT / BLOCK_SIZE][SCREEN_WIDTH / BLOCK_SIZE];

bool init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("could not init sdl video");
        return false;
    }
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "raycasting",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        0
    );
    if (gWindow == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("could not create an sdl window");
        return false;
    }
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (gRenderer == NULL) {
        SDL_Log("could not create sdl renderer");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void snapPlayerBack() {
    if (player.x - playerRadius <= 0) {
        player.x = SCREEN_WIDTH - playerRadius;
    }
    if (player.x + playerRadius > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
        player.x = playerRadius;
    }
    if (player.y - playerRadius < 0) {
        player.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - playerRadius;
    }
    if (player.y + playerRadius > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
        player.y = playerRadius;
    }
}

void update(float dt) {
    const Uint8* keysState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    float toMove = playerSpeed * dt;

    if (keysState[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
        player.y += toMove;
    }
    if (keysState[SDL_SCANCODE_D]) {
        player.x += toMove;
    }

    if (keysState[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
        player.y -= toMove;
    } 
    if (keysState[SDL_SCANCODE_A]) {
        player.x -= toMove;
    }

    snapPlayerBack();
}

void renderGrid() {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff);
    // horizontal lines
    for (int x = BLOCK_SIZE; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x += BLOCK_SIZE) {
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, x, 0, x, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }
    // verticle line
    for (int y = BLOCK_SIZE; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y += BLOCK_SIZE) {
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, 0, y, SCREEN_WIDTH, y);
    }
}

void renderBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == SOLID) {
                SDL_Rect coordinates = {j*BLOCK_SIZE, i*BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE};
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &coordinates);
            }
        }
    }
}

void drawCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {
    for (int w = 0; w < radius * 2; ++w) {
        for (int h = 0; h < radius * 2; ++h) {
            int dx = radius - w;
            int dy = radius - h;
            if ((dx*dx + dy*dy) <= (radius * radius)) {
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(gRenderer, centerX + dx, centerY + dy);
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw() {
    renderGrid();
    renderBoard();
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff);
    drawCircle(player.x, player.y, playerRadius);
}

void quitSDL() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (!init()) {
        return 1;
    }

    Uint32 lastTicks = SDL_GetTicks();

    SDL_Event e; bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            } 
        }
        Uint32 nowTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
        float dt = (nowTicks - lastTicks) / 1000.0f;
        lastTicks = nowTicks;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
        update(dt);
        draw();
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }
    quitSDL();
}

I'm running this on wsl2 linux on a windows 11 machine.
Edit 1: changed player speed to a constant value
Edit 2: removed unnecessary constants.
Edit 3: added second showcase gif
Edit 4: setting the toMove variable in the update function to a constant value makes all movement normalized which indicates that the issue has to do with the delta time.
Edit 5: added entire file
Fixed thanks to HolyBlackCat: the problem was having player coordinates stored as ints and not float which were getting truncated by the int cast rounding down.

Adding or modifying the tiny bits of code you show, does not make a reproducible example. Chaning some variables do not change anything on the screen. What are you doing after you change the coordinates? We need something to compile.

The coordinates are ints, but the moved distance is a float. I recommend fixing your timestep and getting rid of deltatime altogether.

(which causes truncation towards zero)

Adding to HolyBalckCat's comment: If your poll the timestamp too quickly you would suffer more from rounding errors. Does the effect go away if you add a delay in your loop?

If you change float toMove = playerSpeed * dt; to int toMove = playerSpeed * dt;, you will still have rounding errors, but the effect should be the same in all directions. If you change it to int toMove = roundf(playerSpeed * dt);, you will still have rounding errors, but they can round up as well as down. To avoid excessive accumulation of rounding errors, store the player coordinates as floating point numbers.
